# Wordpress display the posted date

Tags: wordpress

I display a list of my recently posted custom posts. However i would like to display when it was posted with the get_the_date() function.

I would like the date to be displayed like this.

If it is posted today: just the time it was posted (18:24)

If it was posted this year: The day + month (22 may)

If it was posted before the current year: The normal date (2016-10-11)

Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance! /Molle

Comment: There is a way to answer "is this possible" without writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible to do, provided you can write PHP yourself within your WordPress page or create your own template to take advantage of said PHP.

If you have the date of the post loaded in a variable already (assuming you do), then you can use your own logic (if, else is statements as literally stated by your question) to parse out the day and year.

Read more on date formatting to get the desired output you wish:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php